# Bootstrap 4 spacing in tables

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table, bootstrap-4

There is a gap between elements of an input group, if put into a table.

```html
<link href="https://rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<p>This is fine</p>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-addon">a</div>
      <div class="input-group-addon">b</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>There is a gap between spans in tables</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon">a</div>
        <div class="input-group-addon">b</div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How can I get rid of this gap?

Comment: Any way to actually show us what's happening? Or create a JSFiddle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try removing the `border-spacing` added by the table. Alternatively, you can set the `border-collapse` to `collapse` if you prefer the way that looks.

`border-spacing` is [inherited by default](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/border-spacing) in CSS by child elements. `input-group` is set to `display: table` which means it inherits the `borders-spacing: 2px` from the parent table. This means it will be applied to `input-group-addon`s since they are being displayed as table cells.

```css
table .input-group {
  border-spacing: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<p>This is fine</p>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-addon">a</div>
      <div class="input-group-addon">b</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Previously a gap between elements</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon">a</div>
        <div class="input-group-addon">b</div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I understand that border spacing effects the spacing between cells. But why does it affect the content inside of a cell? In case you still want spacing between cells, but not inside the input group.

Comment: Added explanation. In short: `input-group` is a table and inherits `border-spacing` from the parent table. Modifying ` table .input-group` will only affect changes on the input-group class, not all tables/table elements.